# Azure DevOps - Undo From Updating "Automation status" to Automated for Test cases

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automation

Is there a way to undo from updating **"Automation Status"** to Automated by API for Test cases

I updated the automation status of the test case to "Automated" via the API by mistake, and I want to return it to my "Planned "or "Not Automated".

Comment: Hi @Rawan , I would like to confirm whether you have checked my post and test on your side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could return it via UI.

Click "clear" to return to the previous status.

[image]

You could use Update Work Items API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP to update the Automation status to Planned or Not Automated.